# How to populate new variable with repeated values from vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a vector of values:

```
    values = c(22, 42, 243)
```

I have a variable in a dataframe:

```
    df$variable = 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

How do I repeat each value in the values vector n times in a new variable in my dataframe such that I get the following:

```
    df$new_variable = 22, 22, 22, 22, 42, 42, 42, 42, 243, 243, 243, 243
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `sapply`:

```
sapply(variable, function(x) df$values[x])
```

Hm... There is even a simpler solution:

```
values[df$variable]
```

Comment: What if `df$variable` would be `df$variable + 5` ? Doesn't seem to be a problem for OP though.

Comment: Glad you added `values[variable]`

Comment: Awesome, great solution!  I appreciate the simplicity. Thank you.

Comment: @markus in that case do `values[as.integer(factor(df$variable))]`

Comment: @Gregor Good one. I just thought it's worth to mention.

Comment: Of course, that case comes with the assumption that OP intends to match `variable` to `value` positionally based just on the order of occurrence... seems like a very odd case. If `df$variable` was instead `df$variable + 5` I would probably suggest that there is some earlier problem/bug that needs fixing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rle` and `inverse.rle`

```
r <- rle(variable)
```

`r` is an object of class `"rle"`

```
r
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:3] 4 4 4
#  values : num [1:3] 1 2 3
```

Replace its values slot with your `values` and call `inverse.rle` to get desired output

```
r$values <- values
inverse.rle(r)
# [1]  22  22  22  22  42  42  42  42 243 243 243 243
```

**data**

```
values = c(22, 42, 243)
variable = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

If `variable` is not meant to be the index elements of `values`, then we could do

```
rep(values, tapply(variable, variable, length))
# [1]  22  22  22  22  42  42  42  42 243 243 243 243
```

Or, with `rle()`

```
rep(values, rle(variable)$lengths)
# [1]  22  22  22  22  42  42  42  42 243 243 243 243
```